# Autocomplete not working anymore

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. When I first installed ROS Groovy, most of its commands had autocomplete and I found it very useful.

For some reason, autocomplete of ros command arguments (topic, service, package and node names) is not working any more. Any ideas how to get it to work again?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53353/autocomplete-not-working-anymore/) by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-25**:
Could you try a clean shell where you don't source specific files and set no environment variables and the just source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash (assuming you use bash) and see if it works. (For me amd64/groovy updated today completion works).

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-05-25**:
What lines in the setup.bash script are responsible for tab completion? In some of my nodes, rosrun doesn't tab complete and I'd like to debug upwards from the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Autocompletion is activated using setup.bash instead of setup.sh.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-25**:
Thanks, that information helped.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-05-25**:
Doesn't setup.bash just source the setup.sh file?